# Create nested list (array) of strings from list of strings

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, string, list

I have a list of names. From these, I want to create a new list of lists (or jagged array, if that works better), where the lower-level lists contain variations of the names.

The basic idea is that you take a name and remove one letter at a time to create a list which features all of these creations, plus the original name. So for example, if your names are "bob" and "alice", I want to output

```
[["bo", "bb","ob","bob"], ["alic", "alie", "alce", "aice", "lice", "alice"]].
```

I can easily do this for just one name, but I run into problems I can't resolve when I try to create such a nested list (I'm relatively new to C#). Here's a toy example of what I've been trying:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>()
{
    "alice",
    "bob",
    "curt"
};

//initialize jagged array
string[][] modifiedNames = new string[names.Count][];

        //iterate over all names in "names" list
        foreach(string name in names)
        {
            int nameIndex = names.IndexOf(name);

            //initialize lower level of array
            modifiedNames[nameIndex] = new string[name.Length];

            //create variations of a given name
            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
            {
                string newName = name.Substring(0, i) + name.Substring(i + 1);

                if (modNames[nameIndex].Contains(newName) == false)
                    modNames[nameIndex].Add(newName);
            }
            modName.Add(name);

        }
```

I've tried several version thereof, both with lists and arrays, but to no avail. The error message I get in this case is

> 'string[]' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no accessible extension  method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'string[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Comments are `//`, not \\. I'm surprised that code compiles..

Comment: You cannot `Add` to an array. Use `List` and read about Linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that error is telling you that there is no `Add()` function for an array. As JohnB points out, a `List` would probably be a better fit here.

Second, I don't like the `string[][]` anyway. I'd use `IDictionary<string, IList<string>>`, storing your original name as the key, and the modified names as the value. That way the original and modified versions are stored together and you don't need to cross reference `names` with `modifiedNames` (one of which is a `List` and the other (currently) an array).

```
IDictionary<string, IList<string>> names = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>();

names.Add("alice", new List<string>());
names.Add("bob", new List<string>());
names.Add("curt", new List<string>());

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IList<string>> name in names)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < name.Key.Length; i++)
    {
        string newName = name.Key.Substring(0, i) + name.Key.Substring(i + 1);

        if (!name.Value.Contains(newName))
        {
            name.Value.Add(newName);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a list of lists (of string) while you are working in the method and then converting it into an array of array before returning?  Or even just returning a list of list, if the return type is not set in stone?

Here is a suggestion:

```
    var names = new List<string>()
    {
        "alice",
        "bob",
        "curt"
    };

    var nameVariations = new List<List<string>>();
    foreach (var name in names)
    {
        var variationsOfName = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            var newName = name.Substring(0, i) + name.Substring(i + 1);

            if (!variationsOfName.Contains(newName))
            {
                variationsOfName.Add(newName);
            }
        }

        nameVariations.Add(variationsOfName);
    }

    return nameVariations.Select(variationsOfName => variationsOfName.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Note: for this to compile you'll need to add Linq (using System.Linq;).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in two steps. First, write a simple method that will get a list of name variations for a single name. We can simplify the code using some `System.Linq` extension methods, like [`Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__) and [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=netframework-4.7.2). The `Select` statement below treats the string as a character array, and for each character `t` at index `i`, it selects the substring from `name` up to that character and adds the substring from `name` after that character, returning an `IEnumerable<string>`, which we create a new `List<string>` from. Then we finally add the original `name` to the list and return it:

```
public static List<string> GetNameVariations(string name)
{
    var results = name.Select((t, i) =>
        name.Substring(0, i) + name.Substring(i + 1, name.Length - (i + 1)))
        .ToList();

    results.Add(name);

    return results;
}
```

And then we can use this method to get a `List<List<string>>` of names from a list of names using another method. Here we are calling `GetNameVariations` for each name in `names` (which returns a new `List<string>` for each name), and returning these lists in a new `List<List<string>>`:

```
public static List<List<string>> GetNameVariations(List<string> names)
{
    return names.Select(GetNameVariations).ToList();
}
```

In use, this might look like (using your example):

```
private static void Main()
{
    var names = new List<string> {"bob", "alice", "curt"};

    foreach (var nameVariations in GetNameVariations(names))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", nameVariations));
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your logic by using [`String.Remove(i, 1)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_System_Int32_) to remove one character at a time, iterating over values of `i` for the length of the string. You can write your query as a one-liner:

```
var result = names.Select(name => name.Select((_, i) => name.Remove(i, 1)).Reverse().Concat(new[] { name }).ToList()).ToList();
```

Reformatted for readability:

```
var result = names
    .Select(name => 
        name.Select((_, i) => name.Remove(i, 1))
            .Reverse()
            .Concat(new[] { name })
            .ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a fairly simple way to go:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>()
{
    "alice",
    "bob",
    "curt"
};

string[][] modifiedNames =
    names
        .Select(name =>
            Enumerable
                .Range(0, name.Length)
                .Select(x => name.Substring(0, x) + name.Substring(x + 1))
                .Concat(new [] { name })
                .ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

That gives:

[image: modifiedNames]